# Sending data from HTML page to Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I am trying to save data to google sheet. First i'm importing data from a google sheet (i put checkboxes to the imported data in a table) and after the user checks some checkboxes, i want to store the data from the table in another google sheet
Any suggestion how do i export multiple rows to google sheet?
At the moment it stores only in one row, and it stores only the checkbox data

My HTML code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container register">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-align form-new" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                            <h3 class="register-heading">Prezente - T1</h3>
                            <div class="row register-form">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <form method="post" autocomplete="off" name="google-sheet">
                                        
                                    <table id="prezenta">
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>Nume</th>
                                        <th>Lipseste</th>
                                        <th>Ramane dupa orar</th>
                                        </tr>       
                                    </table>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btnSubmit btn-block" value="Trimite" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

          
          <script>
            const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxIAi4IudTA8oMhNsnkGRgWfmMwp1V9z6k7UAaCVhOGkBc3fnQ/exec'
            const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
          
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
              e.preventDefault()
              fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                .then(response => alert("Prezenta trimisa..! Va multumim..."))
                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
            })
            
            
            let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).feed.entry;
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let angajat = data[i]["gsx$_cn6ca"]["$t"];
      document.getElementById("prezenta").innerHTML +=
       '<tr>' +
       '<td type="text" id="Name" name="Name">' + angajat + '</td>' +
       '<td><input type="checkbox" id="lipseste" name="lipseste"/></td>' +
       '<td><input type="checkbox" id="ramane" name="ramane"/></td>' +
       '</tr>';
    }
  }
};
  
xmlhttp.open(
  "GET",
  "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1woOBg4xOKvu8VcZAQMZPhVLejF_nNnqh-CjpwVlRu-Q/od6/public/values?alt=json",
  true
);
xmlhttp.send();
          </script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to import it after submitting into another google sheet
My google sheet script:

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
        var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
        function intialSetup () {
          var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
        }
        function doPost (e) {
          var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
          lock.tryLock(10000)
          try {
            var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
            var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

            var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
            var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

            var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
              return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
            })
            sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }
          catch (e) {
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }
          finally {
            lock.releaseLock()
          }
        }
```

Comment: What's it doing at the moment? Is this a Web app? A Sheets add-on?

Comment: I have this html page http://jsfiddle.net/palbotond/f15qd2t0/13/  and i want to send all the data to a google sheet... at the moment it sends only the checkbox value.. and only for one line... any sugestion?

Comment: Which checkbox? Which line? On what event? Can you please edit your question to include more details on what your code is doing now?

Comment: I want to store all the data from the html table(all rows) in a google sheet... at the moment my google sheet gets only the data from the first row and only the checkbox data(if its checked or not)

Comment: did you eventually get an answer that worked? if so, i'd be very grateful if you could share - thank you